# Object is not a function with SendGrid

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email using SendGrid with Azure Mobile Services. I'm using the sample code here for reference:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-nodejs-how-to-send-email/

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {

    var SendGrid = require('sendgrid');


    var toEmail = 'myemail@mydomain.com';

    var mail = new SendGrid.Email({
        to: toEmail,
        from: toEmail,
        subject: 'Hello SendGrid',
        text: 'This is a sample email message.'
    });

    var sender = new SendGrid('my_user','my_ key');


};
```

I'm getting an TypeError creating the sender. The Email object is created as expected. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. From looking at the code in sendgrid.js, the exports look correct. Any ideas?

Here is the error:

Error in script '/api/my_api.js'. TypeError: object is not a function

Note:
I have added sendgrid using npm

From sendgrid.js

```
var Sendgrid = function(api_user, api_key, options) {
}

module.exports = Sendgrid;
```

Comment: Smells like a requires config error.  Check browser dev console to see if the file got loaded

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091170/sendgrid-giving-error-sendgrid-email-is-not-a-constructor/46703616#46703616

Answer (score 1):

Per the github docs:

```
var sendGrid = require('sendgrid')('my_user', 'my_key');

var mail = new sendGrid.Email({
  to: toEmail,
  from: toEmail,
  subject: 'Hello SendGrid',
  text: 'This is a sample email message.'
});
```

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

Comment: The require from github fails with the same message. TypeError: object is not a function. I had tried this previously.

Comment: I tested what I have here and it works fine. Do you have the latest version?

Comment: Version 1.2. Installed via npm today.

Answer (score 0):

`sendgrid.Email` is a method of the object returned by instantiating the module. To access `sendgrid.Email`, you must call the function returned by requiring SendGrid.

Your code should look as follows:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {

  var sendgrid = require('sendgrid');
  var sender = new sendgrid('my_user','my_ key');
  var toEmail = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
  var mail = new sender.Email({
    to: toEmail,
    from: toEmail,
    subject: 'Hello SendGrid',
    text: 'This is a sample email message.'
  });
};
```

Edit: Corrected method names.

Answer (score 0):

The SendGrid package was not being imported correctly. I was thrown off the error because the Email object was being created correctly.

I rechecked my package.json and updated the project with npm install. Everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers above helped me, but I still had to figure this out.

Here is what I did to fix the object is not a function error when using sendgrid.  This is obviously, version specific, so you may have to adjust the version number depending on the version of sendgrid you are using.

Add sendgrid as a dependency in the package.json file of your azure mobile services project.

"dependencies": {
    "sendgrid": "^1.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sendgrid": "^1.9.2"
  },

The instructions at https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs clearly state this, but somehow, I overlooked it.